# ffmpeg cut the video and output the audio additionally

Tags: ffmpeg

I can cut and output a video with:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -t 240 -i input.mov -to 10 -qscale 0 > output.mov
```

Also I can additionally output the audio of the input file by adding **output_audio.wav** at the end like:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -t 240 -i input.mov -to 10 -qscale 0 output.mov output_audio.wav
```

BUT:
The video output is trimmed to the segment specified in the command. But the audio output contains the entire input video.

Is it possible to additionally output the audio of JUST the segment defined within the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -to 10 -i input.mov output.mov output_audio.wav
```

- You can use `-to` as an input option. This will limit the input duration and therefore the outputs as well.
- `-qscale 0` is ignored by libx264.

Comment: Thanks a lot llogan, that works well! Appreciate also the hint about the -qscale parameter. Unfortunately the processing can take some time.. is there a parameter forcing ffmpeg  to just cut out the section without re-encode? (Guessing that takes the time)

Comment: @fox Add [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy): `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -to 10 -i input.mov -c copy output.mov -c copy -map 0:a output_audio.mov`. Downside is that it must cut on key frames, so it may not be accurate. If you need exact times then you must re-encode.